# bash: initiate command inside of a string. - using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

my sed input is as follows:

```
sed 's/ListenAddress=.*/ListenAddress= $hostname/' nodemanager.properties
```

I am trying to run this against a Linux server and replace `ListenAddress={current_value}` with `ListenAddress={hostname_of_server}`

I need  to know how to run the hostname command and have that output be reflected at the end of `ListenAddress=`

Thanks

Comment: Kind of, except that when I use ```sed 's/ListenAddress=.*/ListenAddress=$(hostname)/' nodemanager.properties``` in prints ListenAddress=$(hostname)

Comment: You have to use double quotes.

Comment: Oh perfect! thanks it worked

Answer (score 0):

If you wish your bash variables to reflect inside the `sed` script use, double quotes. The same is valid for command substitution. So you should be doing

```
sed "s/ListenAddress=.*/ListenAddress= $(hostname)/" nodemanager.properties
```

Since thevariable expansion takes place, you need to be careful about certain situations where `$` appear as a `sed` attribute. For example if you're applying the above command only to the last line of the file, then do

```
sed "\$s/ListenAddress=.*/ListenAddress= $(hostname)/" nodemanager.properties
```

Note the `$` before `s` command is escaped meaning that it is literal `$` supplied to the script.